# How to prevent Windows forms' new MDI from clearing my graphics from my previous MDI?

Tags: winforms, graphics, panel

I have created this application as shown in the image below.

[image]

Now if I move my right window a bit to left as seen in this picture down below,

[image]

My first(or the one at the left) MDI window's graphics are gone as shown below.

[image]

In fact, whenever I minimize my form, the contents of both the windows are gone. I am using graphics object to drawn on the panel. Here is the code for my child form. The main form just has a menu file which has a submenu called new which basically open this child form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MDITest
{
    public partial class EnhancedPainter : Form
    {
        bool paint = false;
        string color = "Red";
        int size = 5;

        public EnhancedPainter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            paint = true;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            paint = false;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (paint)
            {
                Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
                g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.FromName(color)), e.X, e.Y, size, size);
                //g.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void redRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            color = "Red";
        }

        private void greenRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            color = "Green";
        }

        private void blueRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            color = "Blue";
        }

        private void blackRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            color = "Black";
        }

        private void smallRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            size = 5;
        }

        private void mediumRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            size = 10;
        }

        private void largeRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            size = 15;
        }

        private void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), 0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
            g.Dispose();
        }


    }
}
```

So how do I prevent this from happening?

Thanks

Comment: We already have hundreds of questions about CreateGraphics() and don't need another one.  Thanks for trying to contribute.

Comment: What do you mean by trying to contribute? This was a genuine question because I was not able to find the answer for this.

Comment: The problem is that you are calling `CreateGraphics`. This is always wrong. **All painting should be done in the `Paint` event handler.** (Also, if this code weren't wrong because it was calling `CreateGraphics`, it would be wrong because you badly leak resources. Wrap the creation of `Graphics` and `SolidBrush` objects in a `using` statement to ensure they get disposed.)

Comment: I'm not terribly pleased with the duplicate. As I commented there, I would rewrite it to be more generally applicable, since as Hans mentioned, this question does get asked a lot. But you have more than enough information from my comment and the linked duplicate to solve this problem yourself.